# Re-execute command by :history option in VIM

Tags: vim

How can you execute a command again listed in the

```
:history
```

option in vim. There are numbers shown. Is the only way to copy the command by hand, then re-enter it? Or is there something like in shell script.

Comment: You could use `/` to search in the history when you open it with `q:`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`:history` is only there for you to look at it.

To re-execute a previous command, you have two options:

- Use `<Up>` and `<Down>` at the command prompt:

  ```
  :m10
  (do stuff)
  :<Up>
  ```
- Use the "command-line window":

  You can call it with `q:` and navigate with search and use the beautiful normal mode commands we all love.

  Position the cursor on a line and hit `<CR>` to re-execute the command.

  Edit a command and hit `<CR>` to execute the new command.

  You can quit the command-line window with `:q`.

  See `:help cmdline-window`.

Comment: As a special case, to re-run the most recent command you entered, there is a third way: you can just do `@:` from normal mode.

Comment: @Ben your comment deserves to be an answer

Answer (score 11):

I use `q:` shortcut in normal mode to open interactive command history window. You just move to the right command and execute it by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>. You can find more information and other ways of accessing history [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_command-line_history).

Answer (score 6):

If Vim is compiled with +eval you can use `histget( {history} [, {index}])`

```
:exe histget('c', 15)
```

That isn't exactly convenient to type, so you can also create a user-defined command:

```
:com -nargs=1 HI exe histget('c', <args>)
```

Thereafter you can use HI {index} to execute the history entry:

```
:HI 15
```

Answer (score 5):

What I like to do is type the first few characters in the command and press `<UP>`.  For example if you want to repeat an edit command of the file `file.txt` you could:

```
:e fil<UP><ENTER>
```

If the first `<UP>` does not give you the command you want, keep pressing`<UP>` until you find the command you were looking for.